# Which configuration does Vim finally apply after setting values in .vimrc, ftplugin, after/ftplugin etc.?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, tabstop, ftplugin

I am editing a python file. My current settings for tabstop are as follows(just experimenting things):

- ~/.vimrc: `set tabstop=4`
- ~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim: `set tabstop=2`
- There is no ~/.vim/after/plugin/python.vim file

`set tabstop?` shows `tabstop=8`

`verbose set tabstop?` shows `tabstop=8`. Last set from `/usr/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin/python.vim`

My questions:

- Why is `tabstop` settings at 8 even though i have explicitly set it to `4` in `.vimrc` file or `2` in `~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim` file
- When is each of the files i.e. `~/.vimrc`, `~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim`, `~/.vim/after/plugin/python.vim`, `/usr/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin/python.vim` loaded?
- Which file takes priority and where should I define my settings to override the others?
- How is `set` different from `set local`?

It would be great if someone answers all these questions. It will surely benefit people especially Vim beginner and intermediate users as all of these concepts are inter-related

Answer (score 2):

`tabstop` is the width of space represented by a tab character in the file, but the width of space inserted when you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> on your keyboard is controlled by `softtabstop` (if it's set to a non-zero value). Nothing weird is going on with order of evaluation, or `setlocal`, or any of the other things you're asking about.

See also [What is `softtabstop` used for?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4244/what-is-softtabstop-used-for) on the Vim StackExchange.

Comment: I have edited my question to make more sense from it. The tabstop vs softtabstop is clear to me now but the confusion of when different configuration files are loaded by Vim is still there

Answer (score 1):

1. `tabstop` is a buffer-local setting. That means that every buffer has its own value. So by setting it from your `vimrc` you only set the global default which will probably be overwritten by `ftplugin` and such.
2. The plugin's code resides in `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin.vim`. Roughly speaking, what it does is `runtime! ftplugin/python.vim`. `runtime!` differs from `source` in two aspects: (a) it searches along `:h 'runtimepath'`, and not in the current directory; (b) it sources all files found (that's what the "bang" stands for), not only the first one.

So, because of (b), `ftplugin` first sources your `~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim`, and then `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/python.vim`. For this reason your setting gets finally overwritten.

This is why usually we want `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim` instead. Also note that standard "ftplugin"-scripts have the guard against multiple sourcing:

```
if exists("b:did_ftplugin")
    finish
endif
let b:did_ftplugin = 1
....
```

So if you really want it, you can put this on top of your `~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim` and exclude all the stuff from `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/python.vim`. Rarely wanted though.

3. The difference between `set`, `setglobal` and `setlocal` is actually the difference between option types: global, local-to-buffer, local-to-window, global-local. To keep the things simple, `setglobal` sets a global value for an option, `setlocal` sets a local one, and `set` does something "reasonable" (tm). In particular, `set tabstop=x` sets both global and local (current buffer's one) values.